# Reject incoming unknown calls using android

Tags: java, android

How to reject the unknown calls using Android

Note that by UNKNOWN CALLS i mean the incoming calls that do not have a phone numbers (Or Anonymous calls).

**Here is my code:**

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                }
            }

            if (!incomingNumber.equals("")) {
                rejectCall();
                startApp(context, incomingNumber);
            }
        }

    private void startApp(Context context, String number){
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("number", "Rejected incoming number:"+number);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void rejectCall(){


        try {

            Class<?> classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            Method method = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Object telephonyInterface = method.invoke(telephonyManager);
            Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass =Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
            Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
            methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Incoming numbers detected well, but once i try with anonymous call, the app crash directly.

If you have a fix about this, you are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: have you considered supplying your crash logs here?

Comment: The log says that there a problem with this line: `incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);` e, The app inable to get the phone number.

Comment: Well, if it an anonymous call there is no incoming phone number. Since you did not specify the type of incomingNumber it is hard to guess what went wrong.

Comment: check with hasExtra(...) before trying to getStringExtra(...)

Comment: @pantos27 how to do that please ?

Comment: @fhossfel I am looking for a why to detect first if is a number or unknown one.

Comment: Like @pantos27 said: if (! intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);) { /* Anonymous call */ }

Comment: @fhossfel Thank you ! This solved the problem.